# Avoid image display after size check

Tags: javascript, php

I don't want to display image if image size is greater than 1mb

called `CheckSelfImage()` on `onchange` event of input type file.

```
if($qy_emp3['KYC'] == 'Rejected' or $qy_emp3['KYC'] == 'No' or $qy_emp3['KYC'] == "")
```

Code:

```
?>
<form name="atc" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()" enctype="multipart/form-data">   
<input type="hidden" name="SelfImageName" value="<? echo $qy_emp3['SelfImage'];?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="PanImageName" value="<? echo $qy_emp3['PanImage'];?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="AadhaarImageName" value="<? echo $qy_emp3['AadhaarImage'];?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="AadhaarImageBackName" value="<? echo $qy_emp3['AadhaarImageBack'];?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="CancelChequeImageName" value="<? echo $qy_emp3['CancelChequeImage'];?>" />
<div class="col-lg-12">
<div class="col-md-6 paddt">
<p class="font-600 m-b-5">Upload Your Picture(<b>max size upto 1MB</b>)            </p>
<input type="file" name="SelfImage" id="SelfImage" class="form-control" onchange="CheckSelfImage();" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 paddt">
<p class="font-600 m-b-5"></p>
<img id="SelfImageShow" src="#" alt="Image Preview" height="200px" width="200px" />
<?
if($qy_emp3['SelfImage'] != "")
{
?>
<a href="images/<? echo $qy_emp3['SelfImage'];?>" target="_blank">
<img src="images/<? echo $qy_emp3['SelfImage'];?>" alt="Current Image" height="200px" width="200px" />
</a>
<?
}
else
{
?>
<img src="images/<? echo $qy_emp3['SelfImage'];?>" alt="Current Image" height="200px" width="200px" />
<?
}
?>          
</div>
</div>
</form>
function CheckSelfImage()
{
var selfsize = 1048576;
var file_size=document.getElementById('SelfImage').files[0].size;
if(file_size>=selfsize)
{
alert('Self Image File size is too large.');
document.getElementById('SelfImageShow').value="";
return false;
}  
}
```

image not to displayed after oversize message

Comment: Before you change the source of the actual image, you must have to take the old image src into the input hidden field. Update that hidden field only when image is satisfy your condition

Comment: Thanks i already taken hidden input type where i am storing the old image name from database. <input type="hidden" name="SelfImageName" value="<? echo $qy_emp3['SelfImage'];?>" />

Comment: Please update your latest code

Comment: I uploaded my full code. It shows the alert message regarding file size bu still display the image..

Comment: hello...any suggestion plz

Comment: Could you please specify your problem very clearly? I will help you for sure.

Comment: i want image to display in img tag only when the size condition met. My code gives alert whenever the image is selected and is oversized but after message the selected image displayed in img tag (no matter size is) which it should not...image selection is done by the user..

Comment: Have you checked the solution provided by me? Still facing issue than let me know

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make the value as blank or null. Actually you have to set the attribute of image called src as the null value.

```
    ?>
    <form name="atc" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()" enctype="multipart/form-data">   
    <input type="hidden" name="SelfImageName" value="<? echo $qy_emp3['SelfImage'];?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="PanImageName" value="<? echo $qy_emp3['PanImage'];?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="AadhaarImageName" value="<? echo $qy_emp3['AadhaarImage'];?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="AadhaarImageBackName" value="<? echo $qy_emp3['AadhaarImageBack'];?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="CancelChequeImageName" value="<? echo $qy_emp3['CancelChequeImage'];?>" />
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="col-md-6 paddt">
            <p class="font-600 m-b-5">Upload Your Picture(<b>max size upto 1MB</b>)            </p>
            <input type="file" name="SelfImage" id="SelfImage" class="form-control" onchange="CheckSelfImage();" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 paddt">
            <p class="font-600 m-b-5"></p>
            <img id="SelfImageShow" src="#" alt="Image Preview" height="200px" width="200px" />
            <?
            if($qy_emp3['SelfImage'] != "")
            {
            ?>
            <a href="images/<? echo $qy_emp3['SelfImage'];?>" target="_blank">
            <img src="images/<? echo $qy_emp3['SelfImage'];?>" alt="Current Image" height="200px" width="200px" />
            </a>
            <?
            }
            else
            {
            ?>
            <img src="images/<? echo $qy_emp3['SelfImage'];?>" alt="Current Image" height="200px" width="200px" />
            <?
            }
            ?>          
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
function CheckSelfImage()
{
var selfsize = 1048576;
var file_size=document.getElementById('SelfImage').files[0].size;
if(file_size>=selfsize)
{
alert('Self Image File size is too large.');
$("SelfImageShow").attr("src","");
return false;
}  
}
```

Comment: still not working...there must be some change in the below line of code...<img id="SelfImageShow" src="#" alt="Image Preview" height="200px" width="200px" /> there are 2 image previews...one displaying the image already in the database and one which user will upload....i need to check on Image Preview id="SelfImageShow"

Comment: i made changes in function and it works....function CheckSelfImage()
 {
  var selfsize = 1048576;
  var file_size=document.getElementById('SelfImage').files[0].size;
  if(file_size>=selfsize)
  {
   alert('Self Image File size is too large.');
   document.getElementById('SelfImageShow').style.display="none";
   return false;
  }
  else if(file_size <=1048576)  
  {
   $('#SelfImageShow').show();
  }
 }